# Circular determinant problem

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm stuck in this question:
How calculate this determinant ?
$$\Delta=\left|\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&2&3&\cdots&\cdots&n\\
n&1&2&\cdots&\cdots& n-1\\
n-1&n&1&\cdots&\cdots&n-2\\
\vdots &\ddots & \ddots&\ddots&&\vdots\\
\vdots &\ddots & \ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
2&3&4&\cdots&\cdots&1
\end{array}\right|$$
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The determinants for the first eight $n$s are $1,-3,18,-160,1875, 27126, 466186, 9275064$. Apparently they are part of the OEIS sequence [A052182](http://oeis.org/A052182), which is given by the formula $(-n)^{n-1}(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the matrix with determinant $\Delta$ is [circulant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), its eigenvalues $\{\lambda_j\}_{j=1}^n$ are given by

$$\lambda_j=1+2\omega_j+3\omega_j^2+\ldots+n\omega_j^{n-1},$$

where $\omega_j=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij}{n}\right)$. The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.

For an explicit formula not involving products and sums, see sequence [A052182](https://oeis.org/A052182) in OEIS. It can be shown that

$$\Delta(n)=(-1)^{n-1} \cdot n^{n-2} \cdot \frac{n^2+n}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll do the case $n=4$ and leave the general case for you.

It is useful to recall how elementary row operations effect the value of determinant, see for example
[ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant).

We get
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
\overset{(1)}=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
10 & 10 & 10 & 10
\end{vmatrix}=
10\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
\overset{(2)}=
10\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 &-1 \\
0 & 1 &-2 &-1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
\overset{(3)}=
10\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
0 & 1 &-2 &-1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=10\cdot 4^2
$$

(1): added first three rows to the last one
(2): subtracted a multiple of the 4th row from the other rows
(3): subtracted 2nd row from the 1st one, 3rd row from the 2nd one

There are several possibilities how to see that the determinant of the last matrix is $4^2$. For example, you can use Laplace expansion several times, until you get $2\times2$ matrix; you can use the expression of the determinant using permutations (the only permutation which will give a non-zero summand gives $a_{14}a_{23}a_{32}a_{41}$ for this matrix); or you can exchange rows in such way that you get [upper triangular matrix](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Triangular_Matrix).